# How arrange payment methods order in magento 2 checkout payment section?

Tags: payment-methods, magento-2.1.7, sorting

**I have found the answer and put it in the comment, for quick reference I'll keep this question**

I want to change magento 2 checkout section payments methods sort order,

originally its come as

```
1 - paypal 
2 - sagepay
```

So I want to arrange it as

```
1 - sagepay 
2 - paypal.
```

Need help.
Thanks

Comment: I found the solution its very simple one, unfortunate I didn't notice it, Mangento 2 backend sales payement method section paypal and sagepay have the sorting option. Reference https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/payment-methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods** there you find 'Sort Order' field corresponding to all payment methods. So, provide greater number to paypal and lesser number to sagepay to rearrange it.

Comment: Thanks I found it, now facing a problem with paypal. it doesn't show now